# Fix broken git submodule due to manual directory mv

Tags: git, git-submodules

A directory that is a submodule have been manually moved. Then the git repo is broken as it can be seen by a `git submodule status --all` call. It returns:

```
fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path <actual-sobmodule-path>
```

I removed everything about the faulty sobmodule in the various configuration files (.git/config,  .gitmodules and path/to/sobmodule/.git/config) but it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Please explain in detail what you did: after moving the folder, did you commit the deletion of the old folder and add the new one? Did you call any submodule related functionality in between? I can not reconstruct your issue so far. What git version are you using?